# Override Default Postfix in SEO Lite

Tags: seo-lite

Is there a way to set up SEO Lite so the default title postfix can be overridden on a per entry basis?

I am using the default title setup like so: `<title>{title}{site_name}</title>`

And am using the default for the Default Title Postfix: `|&nbsp;`

Basically, I do not want `| Site Name Here` on every page.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `title_postfix` parameter that might do what you want:

http://wedoaddons.com/seo-lite/tags#parameters

// Edit; Ah I see you want {site_name} on some pages but not all.

You can try removing {site_name} from the SEO Lite template and then adding it using `title_postfix` on the pages where you want it.

Comment: I tried to pass `title_postfix = ""` but that just displayed the default value.

Comment: Just saw your edit. That's a good idea. Hadn't thought about that. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To remove **postfix** in SEO Lite you need to do below changes in **SEO Lite >> Settings** page. You need to remove `{site_name}` from **Template** field and also need to remove `&nbsp;|&nbsp;` from **Default title postfix** field in **Settings** page of SEO Lite module. So, above steps will remove **Default Postfix**. Also see screenshot for more reference.

[image]

After making above settings, if you need **title_postfix** in **title tag** then just pass **title_postfix** in `{exp:seo_lite}`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but removing it altogether wasn't the question. I know how to remove it globally. I need to selectively remove it on a per entry basis. So some entries will have it and others will not.

Comment: I have updated my answer to support for postfix as well